# Running Octave function from C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, octave

I tried to run octave .m function from c++ code on a linux machine as in

[this link](https://mailman.cae.wisc.edu/pipermail/help-octave/2009-April/034429.html)

However, when I try to run the code in the last step ./how-to-call-octave , I am facing this error:

```
./how-to-call-octave: error while loading shared libraries: liboctave.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I remedy this error?

Comment: Did you check where is the liboctave.so in your system ?

Comment: had you checked in /usr/lib/octave-3.0.1/?

Comment: yes I found it in usr/lib/octave-3.2.3 , I tried to add the path using export but it didnt work

Comment: Try adding it to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: How can I add it ? I tried to run this command but I found the same error `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/to/usr/lib/octave-3.2.3`

Answer (score 2):

Many things can be causing this problem. The most common are the following:

1. the file really doesn't exist. If you installed via a package manager, Octave is usally split into 2 packages. Make sure you also install the respective -dev, -devel or -headers packages. If you compiled Octave yourself, are you sure you didn't disable shared libraries when running configure? Build it again, and this time make sure you set the `--enable-shared` flag.
2. You need to update the cache of shared libraries. For security and performance reasons, Linux maintains a cache of the shared libraries installed in "approved" locations. To update this, simply run `ldconfig` (you will need root permissions to do so).